# H2 not recognising regexp_like

Tags: java, regex, database, jdbc, h2

I have a query written to run on an Oracle database which uses the function REGEXP_LIKE to filter some rows from the query. The specific function call is

```
regexp_like(col1, '[^[:alpha:]]')
```

The problem is when I run the query on H2 I get the following error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "REGEXP_LIKE" not found
```

If I run the query directly on the Oracle database using the SQLDeveloper tool it returns as expected.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Is the problem that you need the query to run on both Oracle and H2?

Answer (score 8):

See the [excellent documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#condition_right_hand_side).

```
col REGEXP '[^[:alpha:]]'
```

In general SQL variants either use a function or named operator.

Whether the above specific regex works I do not know. One should be able to rely on java regular expressions.

Answer (score 7):

H2 doesn't have a function called `regexp_like`. But you could create one using a [user defined function](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions):

```
create alias regexp_like as 
$$ boolean regexpLike(String s, String p) { return s.matches(p); } $$;

drop table test;
create table test(id int, name varchar(2555));
insert into test values(1, 'Steven');
insert into test values(2, 'Stefan');
select * from test where regexp_like(name, '^Ste(v|ph)en$');
```

Answer (score 4):

REGEXP_LIKE was added to h2 as of Version 1.4.193 (2016-10-31)

http://h2database.com/html/functions.html?#regexp_like

https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/323

Comment: checked at 1.4.200 version: [90022] REGEXP_LIKE not found

Comment: Its still there in the documentation and the code. Ask your own question with details if it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly improved version of the H2 user function by Thomas Mueller which supports flags and `NULL` values:

```
create alias regexp_like as
$$ boolean regexpLike(String s, String p, String flags) {
    if(null == s) return false;
    if(null != flags) { p = "(?" + flags + ")" + p; }
    java.util.regex.Pattern compiled = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(p);
    return compiled.matcher(s).find();
} $$
```

Comment: `flags` parameter seems redundant. Flags can be directly passed in the pattern by the caller.

Comment: @Stephan: The Oracle version has three parameters, that's why I need it.

Answer (score 0):

https://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#regexp_predicate_right_hand_side

Regular expression matching is used. See Java Matcher.find for details. Example: REGEXP '[a-z]'

https://overcoder.net/q/8528/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-match-%D0%B8-find-%D0%B2-java-regex

Matches returns true if the entire string matches the given pattern. find tries to find a substring that matches the pattern

Matches (p) is the same as find ("^" + p + "$")

Sampl:

```
DELETE FROM sampledb.user_t WHERE email REGEXP '^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9 .-]+$';
```