# How to register a function on Dialect from a function with parameters before and after the method?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, h2, jpql

I'm trying to make a JPQL run using the `REGEXP` function from MySQL 5.7 database on a H2 memory database. I would like to make a integration test using the same query.

As the `REGEXP` function does not exists on H2, I'm trying the register a new function to make it work, using the `REGEXP_LIKE` H2 function instead (just for the tests).

My query is:

```
String sql = "select o1.id from order o1 where :url REGEXP o1.regex";
```

But I can't figure out the right syntax to register the function. I'm trying something like this below, but I know that is incorrect anyway, because all examples that I found is mapping "normal" functions with parameters, but the REGEXP use a syntax like `:url REGEXP o1.regex` and not `REGEXP(:url, o1.regex)`:

```
public class MyH2Dialect extends H2Dialect {

    public MyH2Dialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("REGEXP", 
            new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "REGEXP_LIKE(?1, ?2, 'i')"));
    }

}
```

And naturally the JPQL not recognize the function:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: REGEXP

I'm imaginig that I need to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
registerFunction("?1 REGEXP ?2", 
    new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "REGEXP_LIKE(?1, ?2, 'i')"));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to make a JPQL run using the REGEXP function from MySQL 5.7 database on a H2 memory database.

Well, I couldn't register the function but I was able to run the `REGEXP` function on H2.

My mistake was trying to use JPQL instead of Native Query to make it run.

```
em.createNativeQuery(sql);
```

When I run the same query used on MySQL on the H2 database the SQL works as expected. So, I did not need to register the function. I couldn't understand that this was possible because the H2 documentation [does not mention](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html) the `REGEXP` function but [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24680427/2387977) mentioned that function exists.

Another possibility that I found (before make the above solution works) was upgrade the MySQL to 8.x version, because they create a new function called `REGEXP_LIKE` that have almost the same signature from the `REGEXP_LIKE` function from H2.

Comment: `REGEXP` is documented on the SQL Grammar page together with other conditions. It's not a function. https://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#condition_right_hand_side

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov so I was looking for a solution using the wrong term. Thanks for pointing that.